# Simple Rebus Question

Tags: rebus

[image]

That's the rebus (right above).

HINT:

> It is a song title.

HINT 2:

> 2 popular singers have used this as their song title

Comment: I do not understand why this question has been closed as too broad. To me, the accepted answer is clearly better than all the other answers.

Comment: @user477343 Me either, but I think they thought that because I accepted the answer a bit late.

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah, that makes sense. Still, 'tis a good puzzle! I can upvote in $48$ minutes (I've reached my daily voting limit) :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> [Two is better than one](http://taylorswift.wikia.com/wiki/Two_Is_Better_Than_One) by Boys like Girls?

Comment: Yes! I originally looked for Taylor Swift, but noticed that they collaborated together.

Answer (score 2):

It's:

> [2 Become 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Become_1) by the [Spice Girls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spice_Girls). (2 into 1)

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Countdown (Maybe from [The Final Countdown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jK-NcRmVcw)?)

My reasoning:

> If you open the image in a new tab, you can see there is extra space on the right, so I imagine that you have to imagine the rest: 2 > 1 > 0 > -1 and so on, which is basically a count down, or "counting down".

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Going Down-Freddie King

Because

> It is going down from two

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> The One on the Right Is on the Left by Johnny Cash?

Reasoning:

> The one is to the right of the two, but if you were to open the image, it is off centre to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> [Two in One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VefNgCprdQU) - Indian Song